# PassportJS - using multiple local strategies simultaneously

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I need to implement two LOCAL strategies using Passportjs, which might have to be available simultaneously.

Here is the scenario: Let's say I have an user and a room, where each has name and password for authentication. Clearly I can define two separate local strategies with different names (e.g. 'user-local' and 'room-local') and on successful name and password validation to return corresponding object -`user` or `room`.
I can also differentiate object types inside `serializeUser` / `deserializeUser` methods.
The issue I have got is that `req.login` method populates one and one only variable - `req.user` after each successful authentication.
Therefore, if I authenticate successfully as an user, `req.user` holds my `User` object. If later I authenticate as a room, the same `req.user` now has been populated with `Room` object, overriding previous `User` object. This causes troubles for me, since I need to access specific object methods & fields via `req.user` for both objects (when both authentications are done successfully).
Same goes for `req.isAuthenticated` method - it will return `true` / `false` based on the last authentication result, overriding the previous one.

How can I do what I need?

Comment: This helped me
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/287 Just need to setup multiple local strategies and use appropriate ones in your route.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is able to log-in straight away with the room credentials without having to do it with the user's one first then you have 2 authentication logic that can be aggregated to each other later on. I'd **store it in a session** before logging in again, or implement a new authentication system that would store user / room info in different `req` variables.

Passportjs helps you handling single user authentication logic with many different strategies types, let's say one user per session (using session is the recommended way).

Comment: ok if PassportJS is not able to implement required authentication logic - any other alternatives capable to do that?

Comment: I don't think so, your scenario is very specific. Passportjs logic for user + password authentication (local strategy) is very straightforward  , take a look into that =) and maybe implement your own. "ain't nobody got time for that!" - go for storing it in a session :)